# Cannot Insert By Using Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, linq, entity-framework

I have to do Insertion by using Entity Framework and Linq query. For the entity class, all fields are not nullable on the database table. I got some essential field values of the entity class which are only needed to create a row on the table. But the rest field are going as nullable from entity. Please suggest me a method to prevent, so that if I will not give these field values, entity will not send it as null to db table and can create a new row on table.

Comment: If you have set the fields as not nullable, then what you are describing is not possible.  The insert statement would fail.  Double check your schema and verify that you have set the fields as not nullable.

Comment: okay.I m trying to either provide all values or changing the allow null on db table. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NULL`/`NOT NULL` are *constraints*. When you specify `NOT NULL` on a column, you are literally telling SQL Server that *some* value must be provided for that column or the row is invalid. You can't allow nulls on a non-nullable column on a whim as that defeats the entire purpose of the constraint.

So your choices are: 1) you make the column nullable or 2) you provide a default value. At the database level you can run:

```
ALTER TABLE SomeTable ADD CONSTRAINT DF_SomeColumn DEFAULT [Some Default Value Here] FOR SomeColumn;
```

Entity Framework does not currently allow specifying default values directly, so you have to modify your table after the fact.

Alternatively, you can simply use a custom getter and setter to provide a default value for your property. This won't put any constraint on the database, though, so it will only work as long as EF is doing the insertion:

```
private DateTime? createdDate;
public DateTime CreatedDate
{
    get { return createdDate ?? DateTime.UtcNow; }
    set { createdDate = value; }
}
```

Comment: can you please tell me how to handle stored procedure that returns multiple values of different datatype in Entity Framework. For eg :On Sp in if, it returns integer and in else , it returns scope identity which is decimal. Can I resolve it in ef side without modifying Sp.