# Can not seed data with EF Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I found the problem, Solution is at comments.

I can create tables and diagram but I can not seed data to table.

1.I installed EF by Nuget.

2.From PM console I wrote Enable-Migrations –EnableAutomaticMigrations.

Model is in All.Model class library and and context methods are in All.Dal class library I did not understand what am I doing wrong can you help me?

This is my context code:

```
using All.Model;  

 namespace All.Dal  
 {
    public class AllDb : DbContext
    {
    public AllDb()
    {
        Database.Connection.ConnectionString = "Server=SEUPHORIA;Database=AllDb;UID=sa;PWD=123;";
    }

    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Line> Lines { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<AllDb>(new DbStrategy());
        modelBuilder.Entity<Category>().Property(c => c.Name).IsRequired();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Comment>().Property(c => c.Letter).IsRequired();
    }
}
```

}

And this is my strategy code:

```
using All.Model;

namespace All.Dal
{
   public class DbStrategy : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<AllDb>
  {
      protected override void Seed(AllDb context)
    {
        List<Category> CategoryDefault = new List<Category> 
        {
            new Category { Name="Organic", UpID = 0 },
            new Category { Name="Object", UpID=0},
            new Category { Name="Time",UpID=0},
        };

        foreach (Category item in CategoryDefault)
        {
          context.Categories.Add(item);
        } context.Users.Add(new User { Name = "sss" });

    }
 }
```

}

this is my category class:

```
 public class Category : Standart
  {
    public int UpID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int LineID { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Line> Lines { get; set; }
 }
```

Comment: can you share Category table schema?

Comment: I have added the category

Comment: please check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17044162/cannot-insert-by-using-entity-framework

Comment: Thank you I read your suggest and removed all not nullable classes from table only ID,Name and UpID left but still it does seed.

Comment: prashanth You were right I found the solution.An inherited class "Standart" was making null to not nullable table thank you very much.

Comment: If I had reputation I would. :\

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the items into the DB context but are not committing the changes by calling SaveChanges() on them. Just add this one line:

```
protected override void Seed(AllDb context)
{
    List<Category> CategoryDefault = new List<Category> 
    {
        new Category { Name="Organic", UpID = 0 },
        new Category { Name="Object", UpID=0},
        new Category { Name="Time",UpID=0},
    };

    foreach (Category item in CategoryDefault)
    {
      context.Categories.Add(item);
    }
    context.Users.Add(new User { Name = "sss" });
    context.SaveChanges(); // make sure you save!
}
```

Comment: It is context not database you can not make savechanges.Btw I tried but did not work.

Comment: Why can you not use [DbContext.SaveChanges()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.savechanges%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)? What does it do when you try?

Comment: I found the problem as prashanth said I was sending null data to not nullable column.And SaveChanges saves data first context after to database not only context.Thank you for help.